Why is $3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3))$ near $\pi$?
$3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) = 3.1415926535721955587...$
$3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) + \sin(3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) ) = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795019...$
$\pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028...$
Why is $3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) $ and $3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) + \sin(3 + \sin(3) + \sin(3+\sin(3)) )$ near $\pi$?

Because $\pi+\sin(\pi)+\sin(\pi+\sin(\pi))=\pi$. Try $3.14$ instead of $3$, and you'll see that the result is even closer to $\pi$.

The iteration $x_1=3$ , $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sin(x_n)$ converges very quickly to $\pi$. The number of correct digits roughly triples each step. Your number is $x_3$ in this sequence.

The next question is : how do you compute $\sin(3+x)$? Isn't it ?

2+sin(2)+sin(2+sin(2))+sin(2+sin(2)+sin(2+sin(2)))=3.1415926520823464086880...
If the initial value is smaller than Pi, it is likely to converge to Pi.

The solutions of the equation $\sin x=0$ are $x=n\pi$, $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.
If you wanted to solve this equation using an iterative process of the form $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$ this process will converge successfully to a root provided that $$|f’(x)|<1$$ in the neighbourhood of the root.
Therefore in this case we can choose $$f(x)=x+\sin x$$ and therefore have the iteration process $$x_{n+1}=x_n+\sin x_n.$$
At even multiples of $\pi$, $f’(x)=2$, and at odd multiples of $\pi$, $f’(x)=0$.
Therefore, depending on the initial value (assuming it is not an even multiple of $\pi$ already) the sequence will converge to the nearest odd multiple of $\pi$ and never converge to an even multiple.

Consider$$f(x)=x + \sin(x) + \sin(x+\sin(x)) + \sin(x + \sin(x) + \sin(x+\sin(x)) ) $$Make a series expansion around $x=\pi$
$$f(x)=\pi
   -\frac{(\pi-x)^{27}}{13060694016}+\frac{(\pi-x)^{29}}{29023764480}-\frac{47 (\pi-x)^{31}}{6094990540800}+O\left((\pi-x)^{33}\right)$$
